# Идея создания временного рейтинга

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Делаю сайт галерею (**Yii2**) и, как водится, в нём будет присутствовать раздел с популярными картинками. Хочу сделать этот раздел на основе **в**ременного **р**ейтинга (**ВР**): 1 просмотр = +1 ВР, 1 лайк = +50 ВР, 1 коммент = +300 ВР. Каждое действие, повлиявшее на ВР (просмотр, лайк, коммент), удаляется через сутки с соразмерным откатом ВР, на то он и *временный* рентинг.

**Сам вопрос:** как лучше реализовать временный рейтинг?

Сначала я думал о простом коде в PHP файле, но не представляю себе полную реализацию таким способом.
Сейчас склоняюсь к созданию отдельной таблицы в базе данных для временного рейтинга, тут дело поинтереснее обстоит.
Какие мысли есть?

Comment: Делайте 1 запросом. Результат хешируйте на 15, 30, 60 минут по выбору.

Comment: У каждого действия надо помнить время удаления, или можно удалять все действия одним махом раз в сутки?

Comment: какую дискретность считаете допустимой. т.е. максимальное время на которое рейтинг может немного отставать. Или хотите истинный онлайн. т.е. дата лайка вышла за 24ч окно и отображаемый практически в тот же момент рейтинг его уже не учитывает ?

Comment: Для каждого действия своё время удаления. 

А зачем мне отставание рейтинга? Даже в теории.

Получается мне нужен истинный онлайн - время прошло = влияние действия на ретинг больше не учитывается, да и вообще оно удаляется, раз больше не нужно.

Comment: но вы же не будете 1 раз в миллисекунду удалять устаревшие данные из таблицы. а раз так, то абсолютно точный рейтинг можно получить только полным подсчетом по всей БД в текущий момент времени. А это скорее всего слишком медленно и обновлять эту выборку при каждом обращении пользователя нереально. И решить эту проблему можно только вводя некоторое отставание "отката"

Comment: например в таблице рейтинга можно хранить данные с точностью до минуты. тогда можно удалять, вернее не брать в расчет уже истекщие минуты 24 часа назад. новые данные в текущую минуту будут писаться например триггерами прямо в момент появления просмотров/лайков в БД. хотя даже минута может оказаться слишком мелкой единицей

Comment: А, так вот о чём вы. В таком случае отставание можно сделать хоть на 10 минут, хоть на 20, особой роли не сыграет.

Comment: ну тогда например делаем таблицу рейтинга: id-объекта(для которого рейтинг), дата, рейтинг. Триггера на вставку в таблицы лайков/сообщений/просмотров берут время из добавляемой записи, округляют его скажем до 10 минут и добавляют требуемую величину к записи в таблице рейтинга в эту 10-минутку (если записи еще нет, создают ее, т.е. фактически делают insert on duplicate key update). Для получения текущего рейтинга выбираем из таблицы сумму по `дата<=now()-interval 24 hour` для нужного объекта. Когда удалять из нее старые записей вообще значения не имеет, можно хоть раз в день или даже реже

Comment: Уххх, прочитал четыре раза, но, честно говоря, мало что понял =) с триггерами я вообще не знаком, придётся исправляться.

Comment: Вопрос наверно в том как долго должны картинки быть в разделе ТОП или как часто они должны обновляться. Чтобы не получилось так что они там пропишутся на вечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте таблицу **tempRating**.
Поля: **id, postId, createTime, ratingValue** 
При использовании каждого действия дописываем строку в данную таблицу с соответствующими значениями. А экранировании рейтинга поста вытягиваем следующим образом:

```
SELECT posts.*, SUM(tempRating.ratingValue) FROM posts LEFT JOIN tempRating ON 
tempRating.postId = posts.id WHERE NOW() >= DATE_ADD(tempRating.createTime, 
INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY posts.id
```

Забыл добавить, что потом можно попросту чистить БД скриптом на планировщике. Это самый простой вариант реализации.